# Utilizing the chain rule to find a differential equation for $\omega(\theta)$

Tags: calculus

I have the equation: $R\frac{d\omega}{dt}=-g\cos(\theta)$.
It desribes the speed of a point in a circular orbit with a constant downward gravitational force.

I now need to find an equation for $\omega(\theta)$ using the chain rule $\frac{d\omega}{dt}=\frac{d\omega}{d\theta} \frac{d\theta}{dt}$.

I've attempted to do this:
$R\frac{d\omega}{d\theta} \frac{d\theta}{dt}=-g\cos(\theta)$
$\Rightarrow$ $\int Rd\omega \frac{d\theta}{dt}= \int -g\cos(\theta)d\theta$, but I can't figure out what to do now.

How to I express $\omega(\theta)$ and how do I arrive at the conclusion?

Edit:
I attempted the following:

$\theta = \int \omega dt \Rightarrow \frac{d\theta}{dt}=\omega  $
$\Rightarrow R\frac{d\omega}{d\theta} \frac{d\theta}{dt}=-g\cos(\theta)$
$\Rightarrow\int R \omega d\omega = \int -g\cos(\theta)d\theta$
$\Rightarrow \frac{R\omega^2}{2}=-g\sin(\theta)+C$
$\Rightarrow \omega(\theta) =-2g\sin(\theta)R^{-1} + C$
Would this be correct?

Comment: You are correct in deriving it.  Do you have any initial condition on what $w(0)$ at $\theta=0$. If you have it you can find constant of integration and move on in life.  Good

Comment: The initial condition is $\omega(0) = 0$, this implies that C is 0 as well.

Comment: Yes, you are done and you can move to the next problem.

Comment: There is still a slight notational problem that has always bothered me; the movement of the d factors. Is there any set of rules defined for the algebraic manipulation of these factors?

Comment: In physics, moving $d\theta$ to the other side and splitting the derivative into numberator part and the denominator part is  very commonplace and mathematically, it may sound not good but for all practical purposes, it is OK